# Load different content in FancyBox2 based on table cell index

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2, css-tables

I have a table that shows presentations and their times. When a cell is clicked, it brings up a FancyBox with the presentation's title, description, and the speakers. The former two items are static, but the latter changes based on the time the presentation is being held.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to change the content of the same FancyBox depending on which table cell was clicked. The number of cells is known. I got up to getting the index of the cell, but not sure where to go from here.

Full page: https://secure.michebag.com/static/elevate-breakout/elevate-breakout.html

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get table cell index
    // Assign dynamic content
    $('table tr:first td:eq(1)').click(function(){
        // What goes here?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since we're talking about static content, my post is long and useless. The gist of the problem is still how you introduce the information to your code - I would create some objects to describe what you want to add, identifying different meetings/talks with their hrefs. Since it's static content, you only need to do this once(as the page loads) - no need for any fancy click handlers and the like.

Sample code:

```
var meetings = {
    "#pwap" : { color: "dark-pink", speakers: [ "Speaker Guy", "Speaker Girl" ] }
    // And so on
}

// Then simply loop over the meetings and do your work over each one.
for (var href in meetings) {
    // Color
    var meeting = meetings[href];
    $('a[href=' + href + ']').parent().addClass(meeting.color);

    // Add speakers
    var element = $(href);
    var speakers = meeting.speakers;
    for (var i = 0, length = speakers.length; i < length; i++) {
        // Add each speaker as a paragraph with his name.
        $('<p>').text(speakers[i]).appendTo(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: This type of jQuery is a little over my head, so I may need some more help -- you lost me at `getSpeakersSomehow`. How would I order this? http://jsfiddle.net/ebbymac/SG26B/1/ This fiddle is where I got confused. Thanks for the help. (The meeting colors and speakers that are attending are just from a spreadsheet I was given, nothing special.)

Comment: Ah, we're talking static content! I completely overengineered the solution then. It's still better if you first associate the information you're given from the spreadsheet with each element(using the hrefs seems like an easy way) - here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/bvQUQ/2/

Comment: This very nicely accomplishes adding the speakers and colors, now I just need to specify different speakers for different times. Could I do that by adding a class, say, on each table cell `<td><a class="fancybox" href="#pwap" class="specific-time">The NEW Party With a Purpose</a></td>` or is this where `current.element` would be used?

Comment: A data attribute might be more appropriate, since you can insert almost arbitrary strings in them(`<a data-time="7:40">`), then you could change your speaker per meeting to something like `speakers: { "7:40" : [people..], "8:40" : [more_people...] }` and subsequently use the time information to select the proper speakers: `var time = element.data('time'); var speakers = meeting.speakers[time]`. Hopefully all the nested objects and literals aren't too confusing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ebbymac/bvQUQ/11/ Gave it a try, but something is now keeping the FancyBox from pulling up; likely my syntax.

Comment: Woops, my bad. element is the <div> with the content that fancybox shows. What you want is the anchor element since that's where the data is. http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/bvQUQ/12/

Comment: Cool, the lightbox opens now. When I click on each presentation, though, the speakers aren't changing. It's using the information from 2:00, and not changing at 3:15; I tried using "Derp" as a speaker name to make sure my eyes weren't tricking me, but no difference.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I didn't really think about this too thoroughly after making my edit. Since there's only one #pwap, you'd need to remove any added speakers and readd them again for the correct time as fancybox opens them - apparently afterLoad must come to the rescue again:http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/bvQUQ/15

Comment: Perfect -- the speaker div it creates stays in the markup after each lightbox is closed, but with a padding change to that div it's not even noticeable unless you're looking in the source. Thanks!

Comment: Once I started adding more speakers, I noticed that lightboxes loaded from the same table row also load the same speakers, despite having different IDs. http://jsfiddle.net/ebbymac/bvQUQ/17/ I've tried changing the numbers but it makes no difference. Would this be better suited as a new question?

Comment: That's because my code was wrong again, and the bug was being masked by javascript's scoping rules(note that in addSpeakers, meeting is never set to something before being used) - http://jsfiddle.net/BGSacho/bvQUQ/20/ I'm significantly worse at writing code correctly than at conceptualizing it.

Comment: Hey -- at least you can write it! It seems to be working now, thanks again!